# Android 11 scooped storage manage_external_storage permission is not accepted by google play console

Tags: android

my app is working fine below the 10 version but android 11 and higher versions do not support external storage. my picker is not picking any document file. but after giving manage_external_storage permission in manifest google play store did not approve my app. please help if you know any alternate solution for all file access permission.

Comment: For picking documents only, you don't need `manage_external_storage`.

Comment: but without this, the picker does not access my document file.

Comment: You might have to change your approach then, check this: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files

Comment: It is pretty unclear what you mean with 'my picker' and 'my document file'. I have no idea what your problem would be. And the whole is unreadable while no normal sentences.

Comment: Storage (Document) access is not working in the android 11 version but after applying Manage_external_storage in manifest it is working fine. but google not accept this kind of permissions

Comment: @nehabairagi did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like below. Create global variable as needed or refactor as per your need. This is tested upto Android 11.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



private void OpenCamera() {

        try {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createFile();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 3);
            }
            //   }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

 private File createFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName,  /* prefix */".jpg",         /* suffix */storageDir      /* directory */);

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        ImageLoc = image.getAbsolutePath();

        return image;


    }



// Open Gallery
    private void OpenGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), 1);
    }




// onActivityResult handles gallery pics, camera pics and pdf.
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

                if (data.getData() != null) {

                    try {
                        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                        File file = new File(Path_from_Uri.getPath(getActivity(), imageUri));

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Select Image from Gallery", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

            }
        } else if (requestCode == 3) {

            try {
                File file = new File(ImageLoc);
              
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("TAG", e.toString());
            }
        }


    }
```